# linq condition in select statement

Tags: linq

I have a linq query

```
from c in db.Custommer
join m in db.Membership on c.ID equals m.CustomerID
select (c.LastName + ", " + c.FirstName + " " + c.MiddleName);
```

The MiddleName could be NULL, how do I replace that null with a space or ignore it?
If I leave it this way, the query does not return any records for customers who don't have middle names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as such:

```cs
from c in db.Custommer
join m in db.Membership on c.ID equals m.CustomerID
select (c.LastName + ", " + c.FirstName + " " + (c.MiddleName ?? "");
```

This should do the trick :)